# Tablerow with Vue3 Composition API without Vue.cli not working

Tags: html, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

My problem is similar to [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760742/vue-js-table-component-not-working) [Vue.js table component not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760742/vue-js-table-component-not-working).

The difference is that I use Vue3, with the Composition API and without Vue.cli as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <table>
            <my-tr v-for="(char, i) in chars" :key="i" :char="char" />
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2"></script>
    <script>
        const myTr = Vue.defineComponent({
            props: ['char'],
            template: '<tr><td>{{char}}</td></tr>'
        });
        Vue.createApp({
            setup() {
                return {
                    chars: Vue.ref(['a', 'b', 'c'])
                };
            }
        }).component('my-tr', myTr).mount('#app');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The table is not rendered correctly - without causing an error on the console:

```html
<div id="app" data-v-app="">
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <table></table>
</div>
```

Replacing `<table>` with `<div>` fixed it - but replacing the table is not an option for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you `<tr>`s are not wrapped in a `<table>`?

Comment: That's right - the output of vue.js is incorrect. In my code (first code-box) it's correctly wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a restriction of HTML, where `<table>` allows only for specific tags as children (tr, thead, tbody, tfoot). This applies to your custom `<my-tr>` tag. The [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#element-placement-restrictions) recommends to use `:is` as a workaround:

```
<tr is="vue:my-tr" v-for="(char, i) in chars" :key="i" :char="char"></tr>
```

```js
const myTr = Vue.defineComponent({
  props: ['char'],
  template: '<tr><td>{{char}}</td></tr>'
});

Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    return {
      chars: Vue.ref(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    };
  }
}).component('my-tr', myTr).mount('#app');
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr is="vue:my-tr" v-for="(char, i) in chars" :key="i" :char="char"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2"></script>
```